# New subscriber notification

Tags: 7, emails, notifications

How can I get an email notification when there is a new subscriber? I can't find this setting on the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module, but I do find "Send e-mail" in "Configuration > Actions".

Does Simplenews has this feature? Can *Send e-mail* actions make this work? if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Enable the **Simplenews Rules** module within the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) project. It will add 2 events *A user has been subscribed* & *A user has been unsubscribed*.

[image]

Use the subscribe event combined with your *Send mail* action to send a message on user subscription.

Comment: The "Send mail" does not have any "Simplenews" token available. I really need the new subscriber information, like the one on "Configuration > Actions > Send e-mail".

Comment: @CocoSkin did you figure out what tokens to use to display simplenews data?

Comment: @Kristoffer Rom i still have not figure that out